# Maven Ear with two war files

Tags: maven, plugins, ear

I am trying to develop an application which will upon packaging will generate an "`ear`" file which will contain 2 `war` files. Folders for those `war` files are called "`hello`" and "`bye`" and are placed on the same level as of the `parent pom` that contains the info about the `ear`.

The `pom's` for `hello` and `bye` packages fine when i ran them individually. When i tried packaging this `pom` it says cannot find `poms` for both `hello` and `bye`.

Here is the content for the parent `pom`.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MR</groupId>
  <artifactId>MREAR</artifactId>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>



   <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>MR.hello</groupId>
      <artifactId>hello</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>war</type>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>MR.bye</groupId>
      <artifactId>bye</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>war</type>

    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

   <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>

        <configuration>

          <modules>

            <webModule>
              <groupId>MR.hello</groupId>
              <artifactId>hello</artifactId>
               <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

            </webModule>

            <webModule>
              <groupId>MR.bye</groupId>
              <artifactId>bye</artifactId>
               <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

            </webModule>
          </modules>
        </configuration>

      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>


</project>
```

Comment: What do you mean by parent pom? Is the pom with packaging type ear your parent?